# Image SEO "content disposition filename" or url?

Tags: image, web-services, http-headers, seo

How does web crawlers index images in the case where you have a service which processes images *on the fly* and does not have image specific endpoint e.g. "image.jpg", but adds a filename as a content-disposition header?

Does it use the url or filename from the header or both when analyzing the content?

e.g. imagine having a service which takes an url like this: *www.example.com/combine/?ids=x,y,z* and adds a *"Content-Disposition:inline; filename=appropriate-filename.jpg"*

A solution could be to have the filename as part of the url although it would not make *any* sense without the GET parameters, but I am interrested in knowing the consequences of the first approach.

Bottom line, does the URL matter for SEO as long as the filename (e.g. through content-disposition) is valid?

Comment: This question is not on topic as defined in [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). If you don't understand why, please ask on [meta] for help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO, not programming. SEO questions may be asked on [Webmasters.SE](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Just to add then yes I was very much in doubt about if this was appropriate here or on some other SE, BUT this is a question on how to design an image manipulation application and which considerations should be taken with regards to SEO and I thought that would still be relevant on SO (according to the _"a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"_ point).

Comment: `Bottom line, does the URL matter for SEO as long as the filename is valid?` <- Not a programming question

Comment: But it is "_unique to software development_" and could easily be "rewritten" to sound like it is part of a "programming question" e.g. _"Is it best to programatically rewrite urls in a REST service to include an image filename or is it sufficient to have a fixed endpoint but include the filename as a content-disposition header in order to get the best SEO rating"_
but the bottom line would be the same...

Comment: Google will attempt all available means to access your images, but will only rank them if they can be accessed via a URL by a end user (i.e., one must be able to access them with a click).